# List<Chip> chip = []; how do I add more chips?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of chips widgets.
These were created as follows:

```
List<Chips> myChips = [];

myChips.add(... values);
```

So now myChips contains a ton of Chip objects.

How do I display this?? How do I display a collection of chip objects that exist in a list??

for example, I'm hoping for :

```
Wrap(children: ... [myChips])
```

or something of that nature. But the parent widget that encloses it must be able to take in the entire myChips list.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
var chip= new Chip();
myChips.add(chip); 

for (final element in myChips) {
    print(element);
}
```

Comment: `new` is no longer needed.